# Проблема со шрифтом: обкусанный шрифт

Tags: html, шрифты

Использую нестандартный шрифт BabelSans. Скачал, сгенерил фонт фейс через [генератор](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Подключаю, шрифт получился 'обкусанным'. У некоторых букв сверху не хватает пикселя, у других его не хватает с низу. В чем может быть проблема?

```
*@font-face {
    font-family: 'BabelSansRegular';
    src: url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.svg#BabelSansRegular') format('svg'),
         url('fonts/babelsans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}*
```

п.с. скачивал несколько раз, с разных мест

Answer (score -1):

А почему `font-family: 'BabelSansRegular';` здесь одинарные кавычки?

```
*all
{
font-family: BabelSansRegular;
}
```

Comment: разве играет роль?

Comment: Кавычки нужны на тот случай, если у вас название шрифта указано с пробелом